# Should a patent title be very narrow or very broad, or does it not matter?

Tags: uspto, title

I'm looking at USPTO patents. I see patent titles that are very broad, e.g. [Mobile surveillance](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:ULOm3_A8WrAC), [Data privacy](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:g5m5HwL7SMYC), and [Location-aware services](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:HDshCWvjkbEC) and I see patent titles that are very narrow, e.g. [Reconfigurable programmable logic system with configuration recovery mode](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:bFI3QPDXJZMC), [Low latency server-side redirection of UDP-based transport protocols traversing a client-side NAT firewall](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&cstart=20&pagesize=80&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:LjlpjdlvIbIC), and [Low latency server-side redirection of UDP-based transport protocols traversing a client-side NAT firewall](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=5JaAHm0AAAAJ&cstart=20&pagesize=80&citation_for_view=5JaAHm0AAAAJ:eflP2zaiRacC).

Should a patent title be very narrow or very broad, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a utility patent in the US it doesn’t matter as long as it isn’t misleading. However in some other places it is not uncommon to be required to make a change to the title.

If the title was “XYZ Device and Method”, but during prosecution all the method claims are eliminated, in Europe you would need to remove the “and Method”. In the US we don’t care.

In contrast, with US design patents the title can essentially be a part of the claim and title change requirements do occur.